# How do you fill in a standalone path?

Tags: adobe-photoshop

CS5:

I created a standalone path by mistake, instead of creating a new shape layer.

What's the correct method of turning this into a new shape layer?

I tried converting to a selection, but I then seemed unable to fill the selection as I normally would, and I'm not sure how/if this would create a new layer from the path.

Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

A path created with the Pen tool does not become an image element until you stroke or fill it. The Fill Path command fills a path with pixels using a specified color, a state of the image, a pattern, or a fill layer.

Fill a path using the current Fill Path settings 
    1. Select the path in the Paths panel. 
    2. Click the Fill Path button  at the bottom of the Paths panel.


or you can

Fill a path and specify options

1. Select the path in the Paths panel.
2. Fill the path: 
   Alt-click
   (Windows) or Option-click (Mac OS) the Fill Path button at the
   bottom of the Paths panel.

   Alt-drag (Windows) or Option-drag (Mac OS) the path to the Fill Path
   button.

   Choose Fill Path from the Paths panel menu. If the selected path is
   a path component, this command changes to Fill Subpath.
3. For Use, choose the contents for the fill.
4. Specify an opacity for the fill. To make the fill
   more transparent, use a low percentage. A setting of 100% makes the
   fill opaque.
5. Choose a blending mode for the fill. The Mode list includes a Clear mode that lets you
   erase to transparency. You must be working in a layer other than the
   background to use this option.
6. Choose Preserve Transparency to limit the fill to layer areas that
   contain pixels.
7. Select a Rendering option:
   Feather Radius: Defines how far inside and outside the selection
   border the feather edge extends. Enter a value in pixels.
   Anti-aliased: Creates a finer transition between the pixels in the
   selection and the surrounding pixels by partially filling the edge
   pixels of the selection.
8. Click OK.

Comment: Thanks, but the "Fill Path" button in the Paths panel is continually greyed out (as are the buttons alongside it). What conditions need to hold for this button to be available? I'm using the Pen Tool with "Paths" (as opposed to "Shape Layers") selected at the top, and "Add to Path Area" over on the right. Thanks...

Comment: You cannot fill a path when you are a text layer or a layer with vector shapes already on it. To make sure this is not the issue then create a path, create a new layer and try filling the path.

Comment: Thanks, Derek, that solved it. Do you mind if I asked why it should be the case you cannot fill a path when I am on a layer which already has a vector shape on it? This is how I started out... I created a standalone path that was already on a layer with another path. Wondering why I shouldn't be able to fill it, too, or else how to transition it to its own layer, without losing it, so it can be filled? Thank you for your help with this...

Comment: To be honest, I'm not sure why it is like that. That would be a good question for Adobe.